# Windows Defender deletes files of my Ubuntu Server

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, samba, windows-defender, file-server

I have two ubuntu servers i use as storage servers set up with samba files share. I connect to them through my main machine running windows 10 and some files on the server get flagged and instantly removed by windows defender. I have even added both servers as exclusions in windows defender but they windows does not seem to care at all. Windows does not actively remove them when i am not in the folder these files are in, but seem to delete them the moment i enter the folder and the files just disappear in front of my eyes.

I need help with getting a way to stop this from happening as a reason i even did parts of my servers are to keep windows from grabbing and randomly deleting files it does not like. Windows defender places the files in quarantine but they are not restorable or placable in to whitelist from that. I have tried everything i know through windows and windows defender but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Unless the files are a very severe threat, Windows Defender will place them in its quarantine.  Whitelist them from there and do that for all such files.

Comment: Updated my question to be more specific on how windows defender treats the files

Comment: Submit them as samples so Windows Defender stops removing them, but can you provide a screenshot of your exclusions, perhaps you have use a more broad exclusion.

Comment: @Ramhound i have tried going as specific as i can with the exclusions as i can but still does not work, and submitting samples will take forever to do with the files as there are quiet a few